# Use Underscore.js to remove object from array based on property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects in javascript. Each object is of the form

```
obj {
    location: "left", // some string
    weight: 0 // can be zero or non zero
}
```

I want to return a filtered copy of the array where the objects with a weight property of zero are removed

What is the clean way to do this with underscore?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't even really need underscore for this, since there's the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as of ECMAScript 5:

```
var newArr = oldArr.filter(function(o) { return o.weight !== 0; });
```

But if you want to use underscore (e.g. to support older browsers that do not support ECMAScript 5), you can use its [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) method:

```
var newArr = _.filter(oldArr, function(o) { return o.weight !== 0; });
```

Comment: Removing implies identity preservation, this returns a copy so It's actually querying.

Answer (score 3):

[`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) should do the job

```
_.filter(data, function(item) { return !!item.weight; });
```

the `!!` is used to cast the `item.weight` into a boolean value, where `NULL`, `false` or `0` will make it `false`, and filter it out.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
_.filter(myArray, function(o){ return o.weight; });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use underscore's reject function.

```
var newObjects = _.reject(oldObjects, function(obj) { 
    return obj.weight === 0; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but my 2 cents:

```
_.omit(data, _.where(data, {'weight':0}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.data = _.without(this.data, obj);
```